# Merging an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
x = [ { a: [1,2] }, { a: [3,4] }, { a: [5,6] } ]
```

and I need to get

```
{ a: [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] }
```

I have tried to use (among other options) `merge`:

```
x.each_with_object({}) do |a, b|
  b.merge!(a) {|k, o, n| o.zip(n) }
end
```

But unfortunately, I get an extra array around the result.

Any suggestions?

THANKS

Comment: Will `:a` always be the only key in the hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }.to_h
#=> [{:a=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe not the most efficient way to get the expected result but you can do

```
h = Hash.new([])
x.each { |hash|
  hash.each { |key, values|
    h[key] = h[key] + [values]
  }
}
```

That way, at the end `h` is `{:a=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}`

Comment: `h = Hash.new([])` uses the same array for all keys. Although it works for a single-key hash, you should use the block form if your default value is mutable.

Comment: @Stefan What do you mean by block form? Moreover, what do you mean by the same array? of I do `h[1] = [1]` and `h[2] = [2]`, `h[1]` and `h[2]` are completely independant, or I am missing something.

Comment: I mean `h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }`. If you do `h = Hash.new([])` and append to the default array via `h[:a] << 1`, then `h[:b]` is also `[1]`, because both refer to the same array. The block form solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
key = x.first.first.first
  #=> :a
{ key=>x.map { |h| h[key] } }
  #=> {:a=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}
```

Note

```
a = x.first
  #=> {:a=>[1, 2]} 
b = a.first
  #=> [:a, [1, 2]] 
b.first
  #=> :a
```

Another way:

```
a = x.map { |h| h.merge(h) { |_,v,_| [v] } }
  #=> [{:a=>[[1, 2]]}, {:a=>[[3, 4]]}, {:a=>[[5, 6]]}]
a.reduce { |t,h| t.merge(h) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {:a=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}
```

Both steps use the form of Hash#merge that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for details.

These two steps could be combined into one as follows:

```
x.reduce { |t,h| t.merge(h.merge(h) { |_,v,_| [v] })  { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {:a=>[1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]}
```

Comment: they key (:a) is not known when I run it (it may be :b or :c)

Comment: You could use a hash literal, i.e. `{ key => x.map { |h| h[key] } }`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I've adopted your suggestion in my answer. Readers: I previously had `x.each_with_object(key=>[]) { |g,h| h[key] << g[key] }` as my second line.